# AWS SSM Agent - Using the aws cli, is there a way to list all the AWS instances that are missing the SSM agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm, aws-ssm

I need to audit a large number of AWS accounts to determine which EC2 instances are missing the SSM agent. Then I need have all those instances and their tags outputted.

Running `aws ssm describe-instance-information` lists all the instances that have the agent installed and are running, but it doesn't list instances that are missing the agent or systems that might be turned off.

Comment: Worth starting with AWS Config to understand how it can help you view compliance history and SSM State Manager associations.

Comment: There probably isn't a way to use the AWS CLI to list agents that are missing the agent, but you could use it to list _all_ instances and then you could just subtract the instances with the agent. (eg in an Excel spreadsheet or with a little script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for instance in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text )
do
  managed=$(aws ssm describe-instance-information  --filters "Key=InstanceIds,Values=$instance" --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[AssociationStatus]' --output text)
  if [[ "$managed" != "Success" ]]; then 
  managed="Not Managed"; 
fi
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $instance --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, Placement.AvailabilityZone, [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`App`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Product`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`Team`].Value] [0][0] ]' 
echo "$managed"
done
```

Save and make the script executable, then run

`script.sh > file.tsv`

And finally import it into excel

Answer (score 2):

This will print a list of all your instances with "success" printed beneath the ones which are managed.

```
for instance in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text )
do;
  managed=$(aws ssm describe-instance-information  --filters "Key=InstanceIds,Values=$instance" --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[AssociationStatus]' --output text)
  echo "$instance  $managed";
done
```

To add a simple but not well-formatted set of tags, replace the echo line with

```
if [[ "$managed" != "Success" ]]; then 
  managed="Fail"; 
fi
echo "$instance  $managed"
aws --profile GC-Staging ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $instance --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[*].Value]' --output text
```

Comment: Thanks! I took what you had and made a couple of changes to pull certain tags and adjust the formatting. Then run the script and pipe it to a tsv file.  Imported into excel and it's all nice and pretty.